# MySQL returning incorrect records to bitwise SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Can anyone offer any insight into what is wrong here?  Im using a BIGINT(20) field in a table to store a bitwise value (there are other fields in here too, but for simplicity i've ignored them for SO) when a SELECT statement is done on that field, it is returning a selection of records for some values, the selection is spot on, for others its wrong.

For example:

```
TABLE A (there is a created_at timestamp field that isn't shown below)
id   flag        approved
1    0           Y
2    1           Y
3    10          N
4    100         Y
5    1000        Y
6    10000       Y
7    100000      Y
8    1000000     Y
9    10000000    Y
10   100000000   Y
11   1000000000  Y
```

Now if i do:

```
SELECT * from tableA where approved = 'Y' AND flag & 4 ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

It correctly returns just the record with ID 4.  All good, no problems.  However, if i do:

```
SELECT * from tableA where approved = 'Y' AND flag & 256 ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Then i get records 5, 6 and 10 - when I only expected record 10!  Its not my code, because if i run the same query in phpMyAdmin I get the same responses, but why?  It must be something I'm doing wrong, but I cannot see what?

My understanding of the second SQL Statement is to say, select all from table A where approved is set to Y and bit 256 in the flag field is set.

Can anyone offer any thoughts?  Its not just with flag & 256 that its causing the issue, there are other values.

Comment: 'approved' or 'confirmed'? You're also quoting the table and column names, you should only use backticks. Quotes are for values.

Comment: Don't treat tables and columns like string values. Read this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html

Comment: `BIGINT` isn't a [bit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-type.html) field. Storing `10` in BIGINT is decimal 10, not 2.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Hi Jay, sorry I meant approved. Ah, that could just be me copying them off the Laravel DB Log.  It makes no difference to the result without the quotes or with backticks however.

Comment: @MarcusAdams That did occur to me, but its suggested on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html that BIGINTs are used for bitwise

Comment: If you're using ticks around the table and columns, or there are no quotes around them, then please edit your post to reflect that; it's misleading.

Comment: You can perform bitwise functions on integer columns, but store decimal `2` as `2`, not `10`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Lol! Sorry!  I was just editing them when you posted your comment!

Comment: @MarcusAdams Marcus, ah! well done - that appears to have solved it ... having just done one quick test!  Do you want to post it as an answer, then i can select it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform bitwise operations on integer columns but you still need to store them as decimal values.

To store decimal 2 in an integer column store `2`, not `10`. You might want to use the [bit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-type.html) column type instead.

Either way, you can use `b'value'` notation to write the values if it's easier for you.

```
INSERT INTO tablea (id, flag, approved)
VALUES (1, b'0', 'Y'), (2, b'1', 'Y'), (3, b'10', 'N')
```

Answer (score 0):

The result is correct, For example 1000 is 1111101000 in binairy, if you compare it bitwice with 256 (100000000) you get 256 (100000000), which is true. The same for 10000 (10011100010000) and 100000000 (101111101011110000100000000).

The flag field should probaly have the value 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, etc.

Comment: Bart, thanks.  Its not actually - the 1000 shown above is actually 8 - as Marcus has commented, I made the mistake of storing the bits rather than decimal ie. 1000 rather than 8.